# Plotting Cross section in a phase diagram

Tags: plotting

```
α2 = 1/2 (κ2 + 2 η2) + I (δ0 - β2 I2);
α1 = 1/2 (κ1 - 2 η1) + I (δ0 - β1 I1);
```

I would like to plot a cross-section for different values of `δ2` but could get the output, any comments would be greatly appreciated.

```
I2 = x*10^12;
I1 = y*10^12;

P = (h ν2a)/(2 κ2a) I2 Abs[α2]^2;

ListPlot[{Table[{(P /. δ2 -> 4 π)*10^12, I2/10^10}, {x, 0, 
    0.1, 0.0001}], 
  Table[{(P /. δ2 -> 0)*10^12, I2/10^10}, {x, 0, 0.1, 0.0001}],
   Table[{(P /. δ2 -> 6 π)*10^12, I2/10^10}, {x, 0, 0.1, 
    0.0001}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.042}, {0, 1.8}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"P(pW)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \
\(2\)]\)\[Cross]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(12\)]\)"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[19, Black], Joined -> True,
 AspectRatio -> 1.3, ImageSize -> 250, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick, DotDashed}, {Blue, Thick, Dashed}, {Red,
     Thick}}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

Comment: Please find a short, simple example of your problem, if possible.

Comment: @– C. E, the code takes few seconds to run

Comment: I ran it but it produced a [blank plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k2jzw.png), and now I have to read to code to understand what you were trying to do. I still haven't looked at it, but in my experience it usually boils down to something I've seen before. It is always appreciated when people simplify problems as much as possible (without all the constants etc.) because then one can often spot what the problem is without much effort at all. And then someone is more likely to help. Maybe it's not possible for this problem.

Comment: @– C. E. yeah, I even got the a blank plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at  `P` you will see it is a list instead of a scalar.  At some point in its definition something has returned as a list and this has made its way through `P`.

You could `First` `P`, `First@P /. δ2 -> 4 π` , wherever it is used. This will get you the `ListPlot`; you could just `Plot` it instead of all the `Table` bits.  However, you should probably work through its definition to find out how it became a list as there could be other issues as a result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Win by seconds :). You can also use  P = First[(h ν2a)/(2 κ2a) I2 Abs[α2]^2];

Comment: @Sumit Whoops, I ment `First`.  LOL

Comment: @Sumit & Edmund, It works perfectly with what I was looking for!!!

Comment: @Sumit, there is a fellow up question: If I now modify the δ1 and δ2 equal to δ0 and I1 = I2 Abs[Conjugate[\[Alpha]2] + \[Mu] \[Eta]3]^2/
  Abs[\[Mu] (-I \[Delta]0 + \[Kappa]1/2 - \[Eta]1) - \[Eta]7]^2 with P = 0.8 P1 and the new parameter \[Mu]=0.1.

Comment: @DavidH, ummm, what is the problem?

Comment: @Sumit The problem is P1 contains \alpha_2 & alpha_2 contains I2 that depends on the variable x.

Comment: `\[Mu] = 0.1`; `P1= a big expression`; `P=First[0.8 P1]`.

Comment: @Sumit, I did that but when I try to evaluate Table[{Re[P1*10^12], \[Delta]0/(2 \[Pi]), I1/10^10}, {y, 0, 0.2, 
  0.2}, {\[Delta]0, -3.5 \[Pi], 3.5 \[Pi], 1}] I get an expression containing Conjugate[x]

Comment: @DavidH. It should not matter when you set a value for `x`. In the worst case, you may get an imaginary part like `0.0 I`. Or you can use `Simplify[]` with an `Assumptions->x>=0`.

Comment: @Sumit, Yeah I got like {0.}, -1.75, {81.3633 x Abs[
   0.608189 + 
    I (-10.9956 + (16000000000000 \[Pi] Conjugate[x])/30000000003)]^2 but could not able to plot

Comment: @Sumit, it takes too much time as I try to plot using {y, 0, 0.2, 0.0002}, {x, 0, 0.2, 0.0002}, {\[Delta]0, -3.5 \[Pi], 
 3.5 \[Pi], 0.1}

Comment: @DavidH, most probably you have some undefined variables. For example, I can see a  δ0 and η3 which are not defined. Use  `Variables[P1]` to see if you have any extra variable.

Comment: @Sumit, I add all the variables.

Comment: @Sumit, I Changed  δ1 &  δ2 to  δ0.

Comment: @DavidH are you still getting an error message or blank plot? Could you post the output for `Block[{x=0.1,y=0.1},your function]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51760/discussion-between-sumit-and-david-h).

Answer (score 0):

Other way to fix that is:

```
 ListPlot[{
 Map[Flatten, Table[{(P /. \[Delta]2 -> 4 \[Pi])*10^12, I2/10^10}, {x, 0, 0.1, 0.0001}]],
 Map[Flatten, Table[{(P /. \[Delta]2 -> 0)*10^12, I2/10^10}, {x, 0, 0.1, 0.0001}]],
 Map[Flatten, Table[{(P /. \[Delta]2 -> 6 \[Pi])*10^12, I2/10^10}, {x, 0, 0.1, 0.0001}]]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.042}, {0, 1.8}},
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"P(pW)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \
\(2\)]\)\[Cross]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(12\)]\)"},
 FrameStyle -> Directive[19, Black], Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1.3, ImageSize -> 250,
 PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick, DotDashed}, {Blue, Thick, Dashed}, {Red, Thick}}, ImageSize -> 300]
```